# How to Throw an Error when the User Hit Save in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In my Column A, I have a selection that lets the user to select "Yes" or "No". There's a required cell for both selection.

```
Example:
If User selects "YES"
 Mandatory cells will be in Colum A, D and E
If User selects "No"
 Mandatory cells will be in Colum B, C and G
```

Lets say the in Row 1, the User selects "Yes" and entered a value on A1 and E1 but he forgot to add value in cell D1. 
In Row 2, The user selects "No" and entered a value on B2 and C2 and forgot to enter a value on cell G2.

When he hit save, I want to throw an error saying the "**Enter a value of the following cells. D1, G2**.

I have this code below:

```
   Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Target As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then

                If Target = "YES" Then

                     For i = 1 To 15
                        If Target.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                         MsgBox "Enter values on the mandatory cells (green)", vbCritical, ""
                        End If
                     Next i
                        Cancel = True

                ElseIf Target = "NO" Then
                    For i = 16 To 30
                         If Target.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                          MsgBox "Enter values on the mandatory cells (green)", vbCritical, ""
                        End If
                    Next i
                    Cancel = True
                End If
         End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Check out the [`Workbook_BeforeSave` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use the workbook beforeSave event and handle accordingly:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
        Cancel as Boolean) 
   'your code here
End Sub
```

Edit for OP's new code:

You never defined what Target is in your code, so the intersect method will always return nothing (if it even works at all).   I think you are confusing the Worksheet_change method (which includes a "Target" range), with that of Save.  You'll have to define what the Target is when the BeforeSave method runs.  I'd recommend running a loop through the specific range of values and checking that all the desired conditions are met.  If some aren't as desired, then you can display a message for the user pointing them to the missing data and prevent the save.

Comment: I know that im going to use that one, my problem is that, how can I read thru the entire sheet and get the cell address with missing value

Comment: @PeterS you don't need to read through the entire sheet if you know what cells to read. `If Sheet1.Range("D1").Value = vbNullString Or Sheet1.Range("G2").Value = vbNullString Then MsgBox "No you don't!"`

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have updated my question with my code. Can you help me figure out the problem on this?

Comment: @RGA we cant use this target range inside the BeforeSave method? What should I change on my code above to handle this?

Comment: @PeterS As stated above, loop through all the values in the workbook when you save and check your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try with one of these two lines. It is not a good idea to throw errors like this, but if you want so much...
This is a message box:

```
msgbox "Enter a value of the following cells. D1 G2"
```

This is an error:

```
err.Raise 1, description:= "Enter a value of the following cells. D1 G2"
```

Comment: Why is the minus? What is not complete in the answer?

Comment: Not my downvote (I actually +1'd for making the distinction between *messaging the user* and *throwing an error*), but your answer doesn't spoonfeed the user with code they can copy & paste without understanding what they're doing.

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't *actually* answer the OP's question, but IMO OP's question is "gimmeh-teh-codez" and doesn't display much research effort.

Comment: Well, I took into account the first comment, thus I wanted to add to it w/o repeating it.